# Why Regex doesnt work in oracle as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace this `:VARCHAR_1` with e.g. from this string: '`if :VARCHAR_1 = "1"'`. number 1, and if after the colon there is something like `:P4_VARCHAR_1` (if it is actually a page item), then just ignore it.
I have already made several of these regexes online through the online builder, but for some reason the rules for Oracle don't seem to work...
Here is an example regex that should actually work:

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^\d_])(\w+)', '1') from dual;
```

Here I expect nothing to change, output: `if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"`
And for this case:

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('if :VARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^\d_])(\w+)', '1') from dual;
```

output: `if 1 = "1"` so how to make this work in oracle

Comment: Oracle's support for regular expressions is limited - [the documentation shows what is allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-7F217A82-4FA5-4CB7-9DF2-B4C879001E47) - so using a generic online regex tester isn't always helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, `[]` character lists do not support PERL-style character classes in the character lists and they are interpreted as their literal characters. So `[^\d_]` would match any character that was not `\` or `d` or `_`.

You want to either use the range `0-9`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         ':([^P]|P[^0-9_])(\w+)',
         '1'
       ) AS output
FROM   table_name;
```

Or a POSIX-style character class:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         ':([^P]|P[^[:digit:]_])(\w+)',
         '1'
       ) AS output
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'if :VARCHAR_1 = "1"' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1" |
| if 1 = "1" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/46_oeqwZ)

Answer (score 1):

The "\d" shortcut for "digit" is not recognized in a character class. Replace it with "[0-9]":

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^0-9_])(\w+)', '1')
  FROM DUAL
```

returns

```
if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"
```

Comment: This is slightly wrong - you would want to replace it with `0-9` and not `[0-9]` as the latter would also include `[` in the match and then terminate the character list at the first `]` (and not the second).

Comment: Ah, good point - corrected.

Comment: now in these cases it works fine SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('if :VARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^[0-9]_])(\w+)', '1')
  FROM DUAL       output: if 1 = "1"                                                                                 
   and SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^[0-9]_])(\w+)', '1') output: if :P4_VARCHAR_1 = "1"  but now i need to cover one more case  if i put it like this SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('if :PARCHAR_1 = "1"', ':([^P]|P[^[0-9]_])(\w+)', '1') it outputs  this if :PVARCHAR_1 = "1" and i need it to be this : if 1 = "1"

Comment: found the solution thank you you were really helpful